# Calling Activity of Library from Android Application

Tags: java, android

I am trying to call activity of library into application project but I am getting error as following:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.sumeru.crop.activity.DSTakePictureActivity" on path:
>   DexPathList[dexElements=[zip file
>   "/data/app/------.ensource-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/------.ensource-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

My package name is `---------.ensource` but I am getting `.ensource-1` instead.

The code I am using to call activity of library:

```
intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Class.forName("com.sumeru.crop.activity.DSTakePictureActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Please help me out; I am open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The `AndroidManifiest` for your Lib `Activity` has to be like this:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.name.of.activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.name.of.activity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And the you can call it with:

```
new Intent("com.name.of.activity")
```

And do not forget to add the lib in your `gradle`:

```
compile project(':libname')
```